# Insert a SET element into mysql db table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Let just say I have table in my mysql db called Film. It has a film_id which is id column and special_features column which is of type SET. Never used SET type before. Special_features column is of type set('Trailers', 'Commentaries', 'behind'),

I want to enter this row in the table:

```
SET("trailers", "commentaires", "behind the scenes");
```

How should my basic sql command look like in php? I am using MySQLi and I want basic sql string.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO (special_features) VALUES (('trailers', 'commentaires', 'behind the scenes'))";
```

how would my sql string look like if I want only trailers and commentaries inserted?

This is just example, not sure if it is correct?

Comment: Nobody understands? special_features is one column and it can accept set of max three of these values: 'Trailers', 'Commentaries', 'Behind the scenes',

Comment: If you downvote there should be a reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it will be something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO set_field(special_features) VALUES('trailers,commentaires')";
```

Here is another example with all Film table columns:

```
INSERT INTO `film`(`title`, `description`, `release_year`, `language_id`, `original_language_id`, `rental_duration`, `rental_rate`, `length`, `replacement_cost`, `rating`, `special_features`) VALUES ('blade','cutting vampires','1998',1,1,0.4,4.99,120,60,0.8, ('Trailers,Commentaries,Deleted Scenes,Behind the Scenes'))
```

However you must be careful with the values separated by comma. There shouldn't be a whitespace between and all values must be exact match(all characters upper and lower case) as when the table was created.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to insert the data into mysql
$sql = "INSERT INTO special_features (row1,row2,row3) VALUES ('trailers', 'commentaires', 'behind the scenes')";

Comment: Actually SET datatype is one column, not three.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to add values to your database, however you need to insert the same number of parameters.
Right now your query is looking for 1 parameter to store in special_futures column but you are passing 3 values.

Something like this would be more appropriate.

> ```
> $sql = "INSERT INTO (trailers, commentaires, behindthescenes) VALUES ("$trailers",     "$commentaires", "$behind the scenes")";
> ```